# Can't make use of grub-mkimage

Tags: grub, mbr

I am trying to create portable grub mbr with grub-mkimage to chainload as bootsector from Windows, but when booting I get stuck at a black screen with a bold "GRUB" and a blinking cursor. There's no key response.

My codes:

`grub-mkimage -p=(hd0,msdos9)/boot --target=i386-pc -o core.img biosdisk minicmd part_msdos terminal ntfs ext2`
`copy boot.img test.mbr`
`dd if=core.img of=test.mbr bs=512 seek=1`

I made this work once, but cant remember how. How can I make a grub mbr without Linux.
I used busybox for `dd`.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to my own question.I had to use lnxboot instead of boot. Because it is made to read core next to it while boot needs cores location hardcoded into it even it is next to it